# Creating a word game

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I'm creating a word game using `UIKit`, and I want to represent the entire alphabet for the user in order to solve the puzzle, here is my code:

```
var emptyPos = [0]
 @IBOutlet var pos1: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var pos2: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var pos3: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var pos4: UILabel!


    @IBAction func btnA(sender: UIButton) {

        letters(sender)

    }


    @IBAction func btnB(sender: UIButton) {

        letters(sender)
    }

    @IBAction func btnC(sender: UIButton) {

        letters(sender)

    }

    @IBAction func btnD(sender: UIButton) {

        letters(sender)

    }

 func moveLetter (pos: UILabel, btn: UIButton) {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

            btn.center = pos.center
        })
    }

    func letters (btn: UIButton) {

        switch emptyPos.count {

        case 1:

            moveLetter(pos1, btn: btn)
            emptyPos.append(0)
            println(emptyPos)

        case 2:

            moveLetter(pos2, btn: btn)
            emptyPos.append(0)
            println(emptyPos)

        case 3:

            moveLetter(pos3, btn: btn)
            emptyPos.append(0)
            println(emptyPos)

        case 4:

            moveLetter(pos4, btn: btn)
            emptyPos.append(0)
            println(emptyPos)



        default:
            println("Error")
        }
    }
```

The idea is the user has to click on a letter after letter to move them towards the empty labels and figure out the right word, and as you can see I went with making each letter a button and each empty space a label, but was wondering if there is a better way than creating 26 buttons for each letter. Linking all the buttons to a single function will not work because then I will have to rely on `sender.tag` which I cannot pass to my function in order to move the letter. So should I continue with what I'm doing or is there some better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you make a custom UIButton you can add extra properties to the button, then change the sender of the @IBAction to your custom class, then just pass the button to your moveLetter and it can know what to do based on the information supplied by the button. then they can all share the same button press function

[image]

[image]

then if your buttons subclass has a @property string called ButtonLetter, you can define what its value is right in the storyboard instead of manually doing it in code for all of the buttons by giving it a runtime attribute like in the screen shot below

[image]

or you could be lazy and just get the text of the button and read what letter it is, but i would say this is a more proper way of going about it, cause this can apply to any type of button where maybe the text on the button isnt actually the value you want to use to do some computation when the button is pressed, but in your case it just so happens to be that way.

Comment: I don't quite understand, would you please elaborate more?

Comment: So make a subclass of UIButton, then add like a string @property to this new class that will hold the letter the button is associated with. also in the storyboard dont forget to change the class of the button to this new subclass which can be found under the identity inspector on the right. then in your viewcontroller class, just make a single buttonPressed function that you can hook all the button actions up to, and change the buttons sender type to your new subclass. then when the button fires, you can access the button and find out what letter it is, and do whats necessary from there

Comment: Thank you, that really helped :)